# Android Wi-Fi Direct hotspot failure

Tags: android, wifi-direct, hotspot, wifip2p

I'm new to the Android platform and I want to create an app that creates a wi-fi hotspot so my microcontroller (esp32-c3) can connect to it. Further, the app should only contain a webview and be able to automatically determinate the IP-adres of the microcontroller so there can be established a Websocket connection to receive sensor data.

After much frustration setting up the IDE, I finally managed to build a simple app and and run it on my phone. My problem is that I always get a failure with reason code 0 (WifiP2pManager.ERROR) after creating a group, which is according to the documentation an internal error. I've tested this on multiple phones (Android 12 and 13) with the same result.

What I noticed is that there are barley examples available covering this topic. Am i making a mistake and is it possible to find out the detailed error message instead of seeing just htis generic error code?

This whole platform is difficult and frustrating. Can someone help me out? It must definitely be possible to create this on my phone, because with the app PdaNet+ I'm able to create a wi-fi direct hotpot that works.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener {
    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv1 = this.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        WifiP2pManager manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        WifiP2pManager.Channel channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
        manager.createGroup(channel, this);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                tv1.append("\n" + action);
                if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
                    if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                        tv1.append("\nWifi P2P is enabled");
                    } else {
                        tv1.append("\nWifi P2P is disabled");
                    }
                } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    tv1.append("\nCall WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers");
                } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    tv1.append("\nRespond to new connection or disconnections");
                } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
                    tv1.append("\nRespond to this device's wifi state changing");
                }
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        tv1.append("\nGroup created successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
        tv1.append("\nFailed to create group (reason "+reason+")");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChannelDisconnected() {
        tv1.append("\nonChannelDisconnected");
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: `I want to create an app that creates a wi-fi hotspot ` Why dont you just let the user of your app switch on the Hotspot of his device?

Comment: `and be able to automatically determinate the IP-adres of the microcontroller` Well if that is needed the controllor would be the server and your app would be a client. But you did not tell who is server and who is client. If your app is the server the microcontroller should first determine the ip of your Android device.

Comment: `after creating a group,` Why do you wanna create a group? What kind of group?

Comment: Why do you wanna use wifi-direct? I think an esp knows nothing of that.

Comment: @blackapps i want to use wifi-direct because i think its less complicated then BLE. I'm also not sure if BLE is suitable for my app because I want to send sensor data 3 times a second. Wifi-direct should work with my esp32-c3 because i managed to create a hotspot with PdaNet+ and was be able to connect to it. I want to create a group with a hidden ssid and a user/password so i can define this config in my Arduino-code. The phone should be the server. The whole reason I want to this is because usability.

Comment: `i want to use wifi-direct because i think its less complicated then BLE. ` Sorry but i suggested not to use wifi-direct but just wifi. I did not suggest bluetooth.

Comment: @blackapps I already have manually create a hotspot and connect my esp to it in the past, which worked, but this is not user-friendly because you have to start the hotspot and the IP is always different and, sometimes even the IP-range. The problem with my microcontroller is that you need to hardcode some values like user/pw/ssid. One important note is that the microcontroller is connected to my motorcycle so it must work outdoor, so no connections to routers.

Comment: `The phone should be the server.` I think you mean 'the app on my phone should be the server'. But that does not match: `and be able to automatically determinate the IP-adres of the microcontroller`. Please explain what you mean. I do not understand your setup.

Comment: `The problem with my microcontroller is that you need to hardcode some values like user/pw/ssid. ` No. that is not the problem with your controller but with your approach. With your wanted setup. With your scenario.

Comment: Isnt there a stacktrace visible in the LogCat which would better show us which error/problem you have with setting up your spot? Google is restricting access to system stuff more and more so it can be that your code works on older Android devices.

Comment: @blackapps the flow will be as following: 1) The app creates a wifi-hotspot programmatically (always with same ssid/user/pw) 2) The esp32 connects to this hotspot 3) The app somehow needs to detect the IP of the connected client. 3) The app passes this IP to its webview. 4)  The webview establishes a websocket connection with the esp32. 5) Finally, the esp32 sends every 1/3 second a message with sensor data.

Comment: @blackapps I don't think Logcat shows any relevant errors: https://pastebin.com/q97v5Cfq

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem: it turned out the location permission was blocked. After giving access, the hotspot could get created.